# How to get rid of Vaadin fallback page?

Tags: localhost, vaadin

A few months ago I tried some Vaadin. Ever since, when I'm not running a local webserver (on Windows pc), my localhost:8080 shows a Vaadin fallback page

[image: 1].

When I have Apache Tomcat running, all works fine, and localhost:8080 results in having the Apache page shown. But when I try to deploy a WAR file via the Tomcat manager, I again end up with Vaadin's fallback, but this time without the image

[image: 2]

How is this integrated and how can I get rid of this?

Answer (score 8):

This is the offline features of Vaadin, allowing you to do apps that still works when your internet connection goes down. It is saved to your browser's service worker and local storage. Here are the steps to clear them in Chrome for a certain site, which in your case is localhost:8080.

1. Go to localhost:8080
2. Open inspector (F12, ctrl+alt+i, or More tools --> Developer tools)
3. Open the 'Application' tab. Close to the end of tabs.
4. Choose Application->Storage to the left
5. Click 'Clear site data'
6. Refresh browser, and notice that you won't get the same page anymore.

[image: clear site data button in Chrome inspector]